# DefensePro 8.13 VM error trying to boot in ESXi 6.0

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtual-machine, esxi

I'm trying to startup a [DefensePro](https://www.radware.com/products/defensepro-models/) VM (Ubuntu 12.04), and I've got the next error when it's booting:

```
-------------------------------------------------
        Global Initializer
-------------------------------------------------
CPU         x86_64 (VM)
Available memory:   16384 M
BIOS version:       N/A
Active BIOS:        Main
-------------------------------------------------
BSP Version:        5.13
Creation date:      May 21 2017, 17:03:47
-------------------------------------------------

EAL: rte_eal_common_log_init(): cannot create log_history mempool
PANIC in rte_eal_init():
Cannot init logs
8: [[0x424f61]]
7: [[0x21656e3]]
6: [[0x4183a0]]
5: [[0x43362e]]
4: [[0xc34f2e]]
3: [[0x194af9e]]
2: [[0x4054d2]]
1: [[0x1945ef8]]
/proc/self/fd/9: 2: /proc/self/fd/9: cmdline_if_not_exist: not found
/proc/self/fd/9: 2: [: X: unexpected operator
```

And the VM stays frozen.

*I get this error when I save the output of the serial port in a txt.*

**EDIT:**

I updated the virtual hardware of the VM to version 11, and now the error is the following:

```
File validation failed.

Network Driver Version: 12.05.00 (May 18 2017 - 20:45:53)
[May 14 11:21:31] UND_UNIT_TYPE_VM  no find any ports for traffic 0, please check VM configuration 00000: ../../switch/undSwitch/merlinMaster/undSwitch.c (884)
 Error 2: No such file or directory
Check failed: ((-1)) != ERROR: ../../switch/undSwitch/merlinMaster/undSwitch.c (885)
```

**I'm trying to connect to the serial port through the network by following the instructions in this [link](https://www.juniper.net/documentation/en_US/vmx15.1f4/topics/task/configuration/vmx-vm-connecting-vmware.html), but it doesn't work.**

Comment: Is the ISO verified correct, it's hash (MD5, etc) matches?

Comment: Yes, the hash is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the **serial port error**, the problem was in the ESXi host configuration, the host didn't have active the serial port license. So I activated the free trial license that contains all the features.
Once I activated the license, I was able to connect to the host through telnet.

And to solve this error:

```
File validation failed.

Network Driver Version: 12.05.00 (May 18 2017 - 20:45:53)
[May 14 11:21:31] UND_UNIT_TYPE_VM  no find any ports for traffic 0, please check VM configuration 00000: ../../switch/undSwitch/merlinMaster/undSwitch.c (884)
 Error 2: No such file or directory
Check failed: ((-1)) != ERROR: ../../switch/undSwitch/merlinMaster/undSwitch.c (885)
```

I changed the type of network adapters to vmxnet3 so that I can start the virtual machine.

Once inside, I configured the virtual machine with the wizard and changed the network adapter to E1000.

```
system internal dp l1nuxRul3s
cd /mnt/applData/DP_8.13.00-64bit-20170612_195609/master
```

Locate the file applStartScript.sh and open it for editing.
Add the following commands to the applStartScript.sh file:

```
rmmod vmxnet3
rmmod e1000
sleep 1
modprobe e1000

exit 
reboot
```